# .NET 6 outputs far larger executable than CSC

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, exe, csc

When I compile a executable with csc, it takes 4KB. On the other hand, with publish option in visual studio 2022 I get 9.91 MB. Both files can be run on a pc independetly. "Release" version of file in visual studio is much smaller, however isn't standalone. How to get same file size with dotnet?

.pubxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
    <Platform>Any CPU</Platform>
    <PublishDir>bin\Release\net6.0\publish\win-x86\</PublishDir>
    <PublishProtocol>FileSystem</PublishProtocol>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x86</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <PublishSingleFile>True</PublishSingleFile>
    <PublishReadyToRun>False</PublishReadyToRun>
    <PublishTrimmed>True</PublishTrimmed>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: `<SelfContained>true</SelfContained>` will include the .net runtime, which will certainly make it much larger. I doubt that your csc build includes the .net runtime... I expect the runtime is already installed on your target PC which is why the csc build runs.

Comment: Does every windows have .net runtime pre installed?

Comment: No versions of Windows have .net Core or later automatically installed, but all supported versions of Windows 10 and Windows 11 now have .net Framework 4.8 installed.

Comment: @Lordoftherings No, definitelly not. Users need to install it (or you pack it as part of your installation)